# Как сделать merge несвязанных веток?

Tags: git, github

Есть git-репозиторий с двумя ветками (master и second). Ветка second была создана через сайт github'a, а её содержимое сразу целиком запушено с некоторого компьютера. Т.е. ветки master и second не имеют общих коммитов.
Так вот вопрос: как объединить эти ветки? (необходимо чтобы содержимое second дополнило/перезаписало содержимое master)
Если просто сделать merge и перезаписать конфликтные в коде места, то проект ломается.

Comment: Именно так и сделать, просто помержить. А потом чинить проект, никакого другого способа нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ветки не имеют общих коммитов, то нужно использовать `git merge`[`--allow-unrelated-histories`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---allow-unrelated-histories)

Если хочется перед выполнением коммита проверить результат слияния, то нужно использовать `git merge`[`--no-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---no-commit), внести правки, и затем `git commit`.

А можно выполнить `git merge`, затем внести правки и добавить их к коммиту слияния при помощи `git commit`[`--amend`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---amend)

Comment: Спасибо, я и ранее использовал 'git merge--allow-unrelated-histories'.

Comment: Хочу добавить для людей, которые столкнутся с такой же проблемой: после внесения правок следует добавить в index измененные файлы с помощью 'git add', тогда мердж будет окончательно произведен.

Comment: @TurboLocb, это очевидно, раз у вас получилось. Но по правилам ресурса, нужно давать ответы, которые могут пригодиться и другим :)